# Cannot install linux on PowerEdge 1800, but I have Grub installed on the system

Tags: ubuntu, grub

I have Ubuntu 11.04 installed on a Dell PowerEdge 1800 machine. For some reason neither the CDrom work, nor does an external boot drive. I can see them once I am booted and into the linux environment.

I would like to install a fresh copy of Ubuntu 10.04 LTS instead. How should I go about. I have access to the internal drives and  grub configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed 12.04 on a poweredge 1800 without a hitch.  It's working great from the first boot.  I've installed mysql, apache2.2 the works.  Grub worked first time.  I did completely reformat the drives and partitioned before I started.  I left the original Dell stuff in it's partition.  You may give that a try if you are still looking.  I know this is an old thread but I thought the comment was appropriate for anyone looking to install Ubuntu on a Poweredge 1800.  All hardware works as well.